# (Python/Linux) Play a wav file with no latency through python or an os.system command

Tags: python, linux, audio, pygame

I have searched for ages for a **latency free** utility to playing short ".wav" files either through python itself or an os.system() function. If it helps I'm running Ubuntu

Example:

```
os.system("instantplay /home/fiveSecondClip.wav")
```

or:

```
pygame.mixer.play("/home/fiveSecondClip.wav")
```

Note that pygame won't work because you have to load in the audio first and as far as I know you can't load multiple at once.

The program would need to run in the background so that the python file can be spammed with inputs and still keep up (overlap the audio)

Any ideas as to how I can this?

Comment: You'll probably need to preload the WAV files into memory and maintain a connection to a sound library in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try afplay to play it by a terminal. Use one of the two commands below.

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

#Plays one music file at a time
subprocess.call(["afplay", "storm-9s.mp3"])

#Can be used to play multiple music files as called
com  = ("""osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "afplay ./Desktop/storm-9s.mp3; exit"'""")
os.system(com)
```